# GIT - Changes made to the same file in 2 different branch are overwriting each other and not causing conflict when merged into main branch

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I've came across the following scenario:

We have a branch (MAIN) which is used as main branch for development, each developer has it's own dev branch created from this main MAIN.

1 file, was changed in similar places in 2 branches Dev1 and Dev2. After merging the changes from Dev1 to the Main branch, we merged Dev2 to the Main branch expecting it to have a conflict, although it merged without issues but the Dev2 branch was overwriting the changes made by Dev1.

Can someone clarify why this is happening and how to avoid this?

We mainly use Bitbucket to help with the merges between branche.s

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't sound likely..... By the time you will run the _second_ merge, what does that section of code look in the 2 tips involved **and** in _the last common ancestor_ (you can get that that commit is by running `git merge-base branch1 branch`)? Can you get that in the question?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that we use bitbucket in the review process and to merge the branches from our devs.. Not sure if I understood what your are asking but, when we do the Merge Between Dev1 and the main branch everything is as expected and we see the correct changes in the Diff. But, when we merge the Dev2 with the main branch, the Diff shows only the changes made in Dev2 without removing the changes from Dev1 that are now in the main Branch, which is expected since Main branch is now ahead, but I reckon it should cause a conflict. I found something --allow-unrelated-histories can help ?

Comment: You talk about a *diff*. But this is not important. The relevant thing to know is what does the *code* look like? Does it contain Dev1's changes after their branch was merged? And does the code contain both Dev1's and Dev2's changes after Dev2's branch was merged later?

Comment: That said, if the "diff" that you are talking about is roughly what I think it is, then your descriptions looks like normal behavior provided that there are actually no textual conflicts. (After all, you talk about "similar" places, not "same" places.)

Comment: After Dev2 changes are merged the file in question is replaced by Dev2 version of the file, meaning all changes made by Dev1 were ignored.

Comment: Let me put it this way... we really can't _clarify_ why you get some output if we are not able to see _the input_. So.... you are trying to merge a branch into another.... you expect to see conflicts _but_ it's not happening... so, in order to be able to tell you why that is, we need to be able to see 1 what that section of the file looks like on the base/upstream branch, 2 what it looks like in the branch you are trying to merge and 3 what it looks like in the last common ancestor (which you can find with `git merge-base base-branch the-other-branch`).